# sqlcmd library error in sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server

I am using `sp_send_dbmail` to send an email containing entries in table `Persons`. It throws following error -

```
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.
```

My  query is below -

```
    declare @q varchar(max)
    SET @q='SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM dw_extract.dbo.Persons'

    USE msdb
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'profile_name',
      @recipients = 'abc@xyz.com',
      @subject = 'T-SQL Query Result',
      @body = 'The result from SELECT is appended below',
      @execute_query_database = 'dw_extract',
      @query = @q
```

I did some research and found that few people who faced such problem could get rid of it by explicitly stating column names and database of the table used. I  did that but still it continues to throw the error.

Comment: Have you ruled out all other suggestions as well? Google results come up with lots of different potential problems. I recommend that you narrow down your problem. First, check if you can send a plain email (without the query results). Next check the query (by itself) can be executed sucessfully, take note of the number of records it returns. Please update your question with your findings.

Comment: Does dbmail work on the server with a simple email? ie, without the query extract.